# Any other way for two way binding using directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I know basics of angular and still trying learn different ways to implement a concept And was wondering if there is any other way to bind data to scope and view other than what I found as below, and which is the best practice. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

I am using jquery datepicker.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.date = "";
    $scope.submitDate = function(){
        console.log($scope.date);
    };

}]);
app.directive('myDatepicker', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            date: "="
        },
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, modelController){
            element.datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                onSelect: function(value, picker){
                    ////way 1
                    scope.date = value;
                    scope.$parent.$digest();
                    ////way 2
                    modelController.$setViewValue(value);
                    ////way 3
                    element.val(value);
                    element.trigger('input');
                    ////way 4
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.date = value;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

way 2 is best. but you work not complete.

- init you input by `modelController.$render = function() {...}`
- some feature is needed, likes `ng-disabled ...`
- accept external parameters

Comment: I didn't get you. what does it has to do anything with ng-disabled. I mean I just want to know different ways to set view and model value from directive.
How can you achieve it with $render or ng-disabled for that matter.

Comment: sorry to not focus the main idea. first, the `way 2` is best, because, when datepicker selected you must update the `model value` , `view value` and other form status likes ` form.$valid,form.$dirty...`. the `model.$setViewValue(value)` will do all for you.

Comment: It's OK. You said way to is best may I know the reasoning behind that. Is it more performer than others.